# Prove that the Subgroup Relation is Transitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and $K < G$ denote that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$. 
Show that $H < K < G \rightarrow H < G$.

I'm not sure of what to prove here since it is pretty obvious.  For the subset relation is transitive, $H \subset K \subset G \rightarrow H \subset G$.  The closure of $H$ is not changed, whether you are looking at $H$ as a subset of $K$ or $G$.  Furthermore, since the identity element of G, $e_G$, is unique, $e_H = e_K = e_G$.  
Similarly, if $a \in H \subset K \subset G$, by the uniqueness of the inverse element $a' \in G$, $a' \in H \subset K \subset G$.  Thus, the inverse also comes from $G$.  Therefore, nothing is really changing except "expanding the perspective" from $K$ to $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Yep pretty much. The only thing you forgot to mention is that $H$ is closed under the multiplication inherited from $G$, but this is clear because $K$ inherits its multiplication from $G$ and $H$ is closed under the multiplication it inherits from $K$. You also need to check that $H$ is non-empty but this is again automatic because it is a subgroup of $K$ so cannot be empty.